# Pass x-editable data from JSP to Java Class

Tags: java, jsp, x-editable

**HTML Code:**

```
<a href="#" id="test" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-title="Enter Something">Dummy Text</a>
```

**Script Code:**

```
$('#test').editable({
    url: '<%=resourceURL.toString() %>',
    send: 'always'
});
```

**Java Class Code:**

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) {

String test = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "test");
System.out.println(test);

}
```

What happened everytime I change the editable value, there's no data sent from editable ajax.

By the way I'm using Liferay for development.

Comment: if you check you HTML, is the url set correctly?

Comment: Yes I'm very sure its correct, and it display my System.out